# Kubernetes API authentication

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kops

I've followed [these instructions for setting up a kubernetes cluster on AWS using kops.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kops/)

I've then been able to run `kubectl create -f ...` commands to get an application running.

I can access (what I presume is) the API at `https://api.useast1.dev.example.com/`, in my browser.

This prompts for authentication, the credentials of which I get by running

```
kubectl config view --minify
```

as per [these instructions from the kops github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/addons.md).

The API then shows:

```
{
  "paths": [
    "/apis",
    "/apis/",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/healthz",
    "/healthz/etcd",
    "/healthz/ping",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/metrics",
    "/swagger-2.0.0.json",
    "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1",
    "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1.gz",
    "/swagger.json",
    "/swaggerapi",
    "/version"
  ]
}
```

Now I'm trying to setup GitLab CI, which requests an API endpoint and a Service Token.

I created a service token using [these instructions from kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/), though I haven't done the imagePullSecret part.

However, when I try to anything on the kubernetes cluster (Install Helm Tiller for example), it gives me: `Kubernetes error: Unauthorized`. I assume this is because I haven't given it any credentials to access that API.

How do I set up kubernetes cluster such that Gitlab doesn't require those credentials to access the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there was a bit of confusion about what the token is.

Best way to retrieve the token is:

```
kubectl get secrets
```

To list the secrets

Then

```
kubectl describe secret SECRET_NAME
```

To retrieve the token.